# Controlling Nav Controller from another

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

My view controllers are sitting inside of view containers.

I'm trying to change the nav controller in the green area with the buttons from the purple area.

In my Main View controller I have:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController,Purpleprotocol,Greenprotocol {
    weak var infoNav : UINavigationController?
    weak var greenVC: GreenVC?
    weak var purpleVC: PurpleVC?
    weak var peachVC: PeachVC?

func changenav(whichbutton: String) {
        print ("changenav")
        print(whichbutton + "whichbuttonstring")

        if(whichbutton == "1"){
            print("change one")
            let svc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rootController") as! GreenVC
             self.infoNav?.pushViewController(svc, animated: true)
        }

        if(whichbutton == "2"){
            print("change two")
            let svc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondController") as! SecondViewController
            self.infoNav?.pushViewController(svc, animated: true)
        }
    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "contentSegue" {
            print("contentSegue")
            let infoNav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let greenVC = infoNav.viewControllers[0] as! GreenVC
            greenVC.delegate = self
        }

        if segue.identifier == "menuSegue" {
            let dvmenu = segue.destination as! PurpleVC
            purpleVC = dvmenu
            dvmenu.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

---

This function does work and I can see the "change one" etc being called but the navigation controller is just not changing..not sure how to get to it I guess correctly.

[image: Layout I'm working with]

Comment: Where do set `infoNav`?

Comment: Edited code above..in the MainViewController.swift

Comment: please look at updated code..

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through to confirm things aren't `nil`?

Comment: new to this so I'm not sure how to go about doing that...I donn't think you can just to an "if let" since it is a UINavController and not an optional varialble.